# Creating a sequence of vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

In my question a vector means a vector of structures of the form

```
struct node 
      {string key; 
       int a,b; };
```

I want to code up the following: Given a user specified number say `d` I want to create a sequence of  `d` vectors `v_1, v_2, ...v_d`.

`v_1` is created from user data,  and `v_i` from `v_(i-1)` for `i>=2` . 
The **size** of `v_i` is the number of nodes in `v_(i-1)` with distinct `key` fields. 
The `a` and `b` fields of the  `v_i` nodes are calculated according to some black box algorithm from those of `v(i-1)`

How should I code this up efficiently in C++? 
Should I use a map of the form 
`map<int, vector<nodes>>` where the int field varies between `1` and `d`??

Thank you!

***P:S:*** I guess one could code up a solution, using `new` operator and some pointer gymnastics, instead of using vectors. But I would like to have as pointer free a solution as possible.

Comment: A map with an int key that is continuous? Why not a vector of vectors?

Comment: continuous? No, the key values are discrete 1,...,d. Basically I want to "lock in" an integer with corresponding vector. i.e. `i` with `v_i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::vector<std::vector<node> >`, but use `vector::reserve()` intelligently so as to avoid reallocations:

```
using std::vector;
vector<vector<node>> v(d); // 0 nodes allocated, no wasted space yet

using std::copy;
using std::istream_iterator;
using std::back_inserter;
// Wish I could v[0].reserve(), but we don't have that info yet.
copy(istream_iterator<node>(std::cin), istream_iterator<node>(), back_inserter(v[0]));

// foreach v[1..d-1], compute v[i] from v[i-1]
for(int i = 1; i < d; ++i) {
    int size = ComputeSize(v[i-1]); // how big a list do we need?
    v[i].reserve(size);  // reserve the space for it, and 
    PopulateVectorFromVector(v[i-1], v[i]); // fill it in.
}
```

The only vector with wasted space and time is v[0].

---

**EDIT**: the call to [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) above is a loop-less idiom roughly equivalent to

```
node tmp;
while(std::cin >> tmp) {
    v[0].push_back(tmp);
}
```

`std::copy` takes three arguments. The first two are [input iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/InputIterator/) which define the range from which we copy, while the third is an [output iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/OutputIterator/) defining the destination.

Specifically, [`istream_iterator<node>(std::cin)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/istream_iterator/) is an input iterator which, when dereferenced, reads the next `node` from the standard input stream. [`back_inserter(v[0])`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/) is an output iterator which, when dereferenced and assigned to, invokes [`v[0].push_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/).

Comment: @Mooing - I swore I'd never post uncompiled code again, and this is why.  I edited to make clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much Rob. I will try out your suggestion. I am not clear about  the  copy statement arguments, (the iterator and inserter) part being somewhat a C++ noob, a quick explanation of that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Given you need range `0..d`, why not `std::vector<std::vector<node> >` as your container type?

Comment: Yes I thought about that. But the size of each of the vectors is not known in advance. I know a vector can be grown / resized, but since my arrays, 'v_i' can get quite huge, this growing / resizing would become a bottleneck in the performance of the algorithm.  Thus I want to create a vector of a specific size before I modify it.

Comment: @Gaurish, you can `reserve` space first before adding all the elements, you know the upper bound for each vector, you can use that (it's only your first vector `v_1` which isn't determined [as it's user input driven], all subsequent vectors will have the same set of keys - if I understand your question - therefore making the construction of `v_3..v_d` even easier - i.e. by copying `v_(i-1)`)

Comment: You can use `std::vector<>::reserve` to give hint about the target vector size, then element addition is just changing the size variable internally and assigning that element (both O(1)).

Comment: Well the size of `v_i` is decreasing and `v_d=1`. So yes I could use `reserve`, because I have an upper bound on each vector's size but wouldn't that mean a lot memory is wasted if I use `reserve`? I agree it that it would not affect the performance however.